# Using ZF2 param() plugin as a module (without ZF2 in place)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a php script that receives variables via GET method.  I can access the variables using `$_GET['var']`, but I want to use ZF2's `$this->params()->fromQuery('var')` construct, without having ZF2 engine in place.

I am interested in 'how'.  In case you are interested in 'why (would I want to do this)', it's because I am working on large existing legacy codebase, rewriting it to use ZF2 step by step.  Next step is to use params().

I am thus interested in building up the needed code to make the params() plugin work.  My thoughts are to write a trait that can be called into my class, where then inside the class I can use `$this->params()->fromQuery()`.

**My current thoughts**

```php
trait ParamTrait
{
    public function params(string $param = null, mixed $default = null)
    {
        //magic

        return $params;
    }
}

class X
{
    use ParamTrait;

    function showGet()
    {
        echo $this->params()->fromQuery('var');
    }
}
```

The `magic` part is what I am looking for to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

params() is just a controller plugin proxy to Zend\Http\Request

You can use this anywhere outside of a full ZF2 MVC app by adding zendframework/zend-http to your composer.json

```
require{
    "zendframework/zend-http": "2.3.0"
}
```

include the ./vendor/autoload.php in your file

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();

//post
$post = $request->getPost();

//query
$query = $request->getQuery();

// etc, etc...
```

Comment: I ran the script but it does not seem to pull any variables from URL.  I used `...?var=test&var2=test2` and `var_dump($query)`, which shows me something like `object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#3 (1) {["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>array(0) {}}`

Comment: I edited the answer to use the correct request object. You should be able to find your request is populated.